# Is there a way to loop through tmux sessions to deal with them one by one?

Tags: tmux

Is there a way using tmux to show each session one by one, so that

1. the user can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to detach to finish looking at it
2. or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to exit that session
3. or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to stop the running process and then either detach or exit

?

Answer (score 3):

You could write a shell script that loops over the sessions, something like (not tested):

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux ls -F '#{session_id} #{session_name}'|while read i; do
   s=$(echo $i|awk '{print $1}')
   name=$(echo $i|sed 's|^[^ ]* ||')
   printf "session $name? "
   read -n1 k </dev/tty
   echo
   case $k in
   d)
       tmux detach -s$s
       ;;
   D)
       tmux kill-session -t$s
       ;;
   c)
       tmux detach -Ps$s
       ;;
   esac
done
```

Comment: oh is there anything built in?  If we need to write a script, how about just `for s in $(tmux ls -F "#S");  do tmux a -t $s; done
`

Comment: No there is nothing builtin to do this.

Comment: Nicholas, you are the author of tmux aren't you? Wow...